# SQL string replace with ID statement

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Is it possible to create a sql statement to do the following:

Table 1 lists all of the drug names, Table 2 contains all of the side effects.

Table 3 contains all the drug names by ID and all of the side effects separated by `|`.

Is there some kind of SQL query I can run to re-create Table 3 where the side effects separated by `|` are the side effect ID's from Table 2?

```
Table1
---------------------
id | drug_name
---------------------
1  | aspirin
2  | zoloft
3  | codine


Table2
---------------------
id | side_effects
---------------------
1  | rash
2  | hearing loss
3  | the plague


Table3
---------------------
id | drugs2sidefx
---------------------
1  | rash | hearing loss
2  | 
3  | the plague | hearing loss
```

Comment: Please post the complete question here, don't use pastebin for that.

Comment: The whole point of SO is to become a source of reference for programming questions, _long term_, not just to answer your specific question now. Putting half of the question on another site is useless if that site disappears or cleans up stuff occasionally. Please make sure you post the entire question here in future. I've moved the stuff across here this time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need table3 this way.

it should be

```
drugs2se
---------------------
d_id | se_id
---------------------
1    |  1
1    |  2
3    |  2
3    |  3
```

Then you can get desired results with a query like this

```
SELECT d.name, group_concat(se.name) as effects 
FROM drugs d, drugs2se dse, side_effects se 
WHERE d.id=d_id AND se_id=se.id 
GROUP BY (d.id)
```

Comment: Correct, a optimized database would contain the table structure stated by Col. Shrapnel.

Unfortunately, the PHP code I am working with was not written to accept a optimized database structure. So, my question still stands.

Is Is there some kind of SQL query I can run to re-create Table 3 where the side effects separated by | are the side effect ID's from Table 2? Or some kind of PHP to produce the table needed?

Comment: @user yes. Write a PHP code to run some SQL queries. If you don't know how to run an SQL query from PHP, you have to take PHP classes first.